# While using refinery ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, refinerycms

I just installed a new rails 3 application on ruby 1.9.2 for the first time using Refinery CMS.
Everything went well using refinerycms to install the application, but passenger is having issues with the application. 
Passenger says Rack can not start gives me error: 
"No such middleware to insert after: ActionDispatch::Static"

I am running several other rails applications on my server using passenger without trouble; although none of those applications are using refinerycms.

Help much appreciated as this is a project in a class I'm taking and have very limited time to complete the scope of this project, would be awesome to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config/environments/production.rb file you have to specify:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

This enables ActionDispatch::Static and is a requirement of Refinery CMS.